# Eclipse for PHP Developers 3.0.2 - code formatting very slow

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Running Eclipse Indigo with Eclipse for PHP Developers 3.0.2 (from the Zend site) on Windows 7 on a dual core machine with 3 gig of RAM, there is a delay of 10 or 11 seconds after pressing CTRL + SHIFT + F to format code.

Does anyone know of any tweaks to speed this up?  I've done all the stuff I usually do upon installing a new version of Eclipse - such as turning off code folding - but this is still unacceptably slow.  Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Comment: Is there anything still running in the background, like DLTK? I've had that slow down the UI when it's going through a lot of files

Comment: Also, check validation, both in PDT and DLTK. It can slow down things...

Comment: It has now started repeatedly moaning about errors building the workspace. I'll be on the alert for background tasks. @Alfabravo, The validators preference page seems to have moved in Indigo, can't find it anywhere. I can remember turning off js validation on Helios because it was just crashing everything.  Will look into that again.

Comment: Correction: there are 2 validators pages in prefs, one (the js one) has only one greyed out option relating to ecmascript compliance, the other is an empty list.